# How to find the maximum value of 3 columns and multiply the other 2 with a fixed factor, then add all together?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "length": [1200,600, 600,1201, 600, 600, 500, 700],
        "width": [600, 1200, 600, 600, 1201, 600, 800, 700],
        "height": [600, 600, 1200, 600, 600, 1201, 800, 700],
    }
)
```

| length | width | height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 600 | 600 |
| 600 | 1200 | 600 |
| 600 | 600 | 1200 |
| 1201 | 600 | 600 |
| 600 | 1201 | 600 |
| 600 | 600 | 1201 |
| 500 | 800 | 800 |
| 700 | 700 | 700 |

I need to find the highest value per row, then multiply the other with *2 and add all together.

So the formula is:

```
highest_value + (lower_value_1 * 2) + (lower_value_2 * 2)
```

- E.g. for row 1: `1200 + (600 * 2) + (600 * 2) = 3600`
- E.g. for row 7: `800 + (800 * 2) + (500 * 2) = 3400`
- E.g. for row 8: `700 + (700 * 2) + (700 * 2) = 3500`

The output should be:

| length | width | height | girth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 600 | 600 | 3600 |
| 600 | 1200 | 600 | 3600 |
| 600 | 600 | 1200 | 3600 |
| 1201 | 600 | 600 | 3601 |
| 600 | 1201 | 600 | 3601 |
| 600 | 600 | 1201 | 3601 |
| 500 | 500 | 800 | 3400 |
| 700 | 700 | 700 | 3500 |

I can find the maximum of the 3 rows with

```
df[["length ", "width ", "height "]].max(axis=1)
```

but I need help with the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a simpler solution

```
df['New'] = df.sum(axis=1)*2 - df.max(axis=1)
```

Edit, was meant to copy this

```
df['Girth'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(x)*2 - max(x), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is that solution vectorized? My dataframe is quite large.

Comment: In which case I'd use my first solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very fast, vectorized solution that takes advantage of numpy broadcasting to achieve very high performance:

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy() != df.max(axis=1).to_numpy().reshape(-1,1), columns=df.columns)
df['girth'] = df.add(df[mask].fillna(0)).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   length  width  height   girth
0    1200    600     600  3600.0
1     600   1200     600  3600.0
2     600    600    1200  3600.0
3    1201    600     600  3601.0
4     600   1201     600  3601.0
5     600    600    1201  3601.0
```

On my *3.6 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9*, this took about ~950ms for 6,000,000 (6 million) rows.

---

Basically what we're doing here is:

1. Creating a mask that selects all the values in the dataframe that are not the max of the row they're in
2. Adding the values selected by that mask (the non-max values) to the dataframe again
3. Summing the resulting rows

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Sadly I don't understand a single thing. If you have the time it would be nice to explain the code.

Comment: @Quixotic22's solution is better because it's simpler, but I'll explain to you mine. :)

Comment: Explained in the answer, @Vega. Basically I just select the non-max values and add those to themselves, then sum each row.